# Turn on display for new notifications?

Tags: notifications, screen, 8.0-oreo

Is there a way to turn on the display for new notifications arriving?

Use case: I enjoy having my display turned off but don't want to manually turn it on to check for new notifications on my lock screen.

Is there a native way to do that with Android 8?

I am using a Samsung Galaxy a3 (2017).

Comment: Some ROMs have a feature called "ambient display" that wakes the screen for a while when receiving notifications, not sure if it exists on this device though...

Comment: And [some apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_notifications#group_543) can do the trick if the ROM itself doesn't (note: link goes to my site), like "Wake Up Screen" or "Screen Notifications".